# How to change my angular controller and node server code to post data into my database

Tags: angularjs, node.js

How to change my  angular controller and  node server code to  post data into my database

**Controller**

```
var app= angular.module('App',[]);
var PD;
var address=null;
var pid=1;


app.controller("Ctrl",function($scope,$http) {
$http.get('/load').success(function(data) {
    $scope.persons= data;
    });

$scope.submit=function(){
    PD=prompt("Enter person details");
    if(PD.localeCompare("")!=0)
    {       
var data=JSON.stringify({pid:pid,
                    persondescription:PD,
                    url:$scope.url,
                    address:address,
                    submittedtime:new Date().toLocaleString().replace("/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/", "$1"),
                    status:'Submitted'
});
console.log(data);
$http.post('/send',data).success(function(data,status) {

console.log(data);
    console.log('Data posted successfully');
});
});
```

Node server code
**Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var app = express();
app.set('port', 3000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
enter code herevar connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '-',
    user     : '-',
    password : '-',
    database : '-'
});
connection.connect(function(error){
if(error)
{
console.log("Problem with MySQL"+error);
}
else
{
console.log("Connected with Database");
}
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendfile('managementt.html');
});
/*
* Here we will call Database.
* Fetch news from table.
* Return it in JSON.
*/
app.get('/load',function(req,res){
connection.query("SELECT * from personactivity",function(err,rows){
if(err)
{
console.log("Problem with MySQL"+err);
}
else
{
res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
}
 });
 });
app.post('/send', function(req,res){
console.log(req.body);
var query = connection.query('insert into personactivity set ?',req.body, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
       console.error(err);
        return res.send(err);
      } else {
       return res.send('Ok');
     }
});
 app.listen(3000,function(){
 console.log("It's Started on PORT 3000");
 });
```

How to change my  angular controller and  node server code to  post data into my database

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: i'm getting following  error 
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)